Moderators: please don't moderate yourself
I recently flagged two comments as unfriendly/unkind:

We usually don't mind self-answered questions that much, but this one seems particularly pointless. Why ask and answer this one?


Just because you're suspended on another site doesn't mean you can ask questions that belong there here instead.

In the first, "particularly pointless" is not a normal manner to talk to someone out of the blue. And the second is clearly condescending. This is particularly problematic because both comments were by one of our moderators, who should lead by example. Unfortunately both my flags were declined.
I also recently made a case that a question should be reopened. This question was closed with one vote by this moderator. I wrote a comment explaining why it should not have been closed, and there are two reopen votes. However, the question does not appear in the Reopen Votes review queue because that same moderator reviewed it and decided to leave it closed, without responding to my comment.
This is not an isolated instance. I previously asked that moderators exercise some care with the Reopen Votes review queue: voting to leave a question closed removes it from the review queue, and the lack of attention makes it very hard to get a question reopened. This question received 5 upvotes but no response from the moderator in question.
It is unclear whether the flags on the two comments above were declined by the same moderator who wrote them, but at least in the case of the closed questions I find it problematic that one person decides to close a question and removes it from the Reopen Votes review queue without engaging in discussion in the comments.
I would like to propose concretely that:

Moderators don't handle flags on their own comments or posts;
Moderators don't vote to "leave closed" questions in the Reopen Votes review queue when there is discussion in the comments;
Moderators don't vote to "leave closed" questions in the Reopen Votes review queue that they themselves voted to close before.


I agree with this suggestion. We have enough regular users that close and reopen votes can happen without moderator intervention, and enough moderators to handle flags when they arise, even with one moderator recusing themself.

Stack Exchange has the philosophy of community moderation: beginning with new users with only a few hundred points up to "trusted users" with thousands, as you use the site everyone gradually gets more ability to participate in the moderation of the site. The elected moderators continue this scale of privileges, before company staff at the top who can do things even the mods can't (for example, merging profiles, or issuing suspensions for more than 1 year). The mods aren't a separate class of person in the community who can only utilise their mod powers, they're still a member of the community, and can and should use all their moderation privileges to assist the community. So mods don't need to provide any justification for using the review queues any more than anyone else does, even in cases such as reviewing the reopening of a question they had participated in the closing of. Elected mods are part of the site's community moderation, not an alternative to it.
Mods do have the power to immediately close or reopen a question, so we mods do have to be careful when we're using that power. Regular users can vote on borderline off-topic questions without stressing because the questions will only be closed if several others in the community agree it's off-topic. The mods can't do that (despite feature requests for non-binding votes), so the mods have to basically not vote on anything they consider borderline off-topic. I'll often leave a comment on such questions, but not vote unless I'm like 95% sure it doesn't meet the site standards. From what I can see all of this site's mods operate this way. No one is trying to abuse their powers here.
Blanket rules saying mods shouldn't use the reopen queue if there's discussion in the comments or if they've previous participated in the closing of the question don't make sense because a lot of the time the discussion is coming from a new user who is just arguing against the very clear site scoping rules they previously weren't aware of, or even sometimes from experienced users who just disagree with how the community has decided to enforce its policies. For example, context-less etymology questions are off-topic now, but that took many years and the input of a very large number of community members, but occasionally I still see comments wanting questions which do not qualify to be reopened. Likewise questions go into the reopen queue after they're edited, but just because it was edited doesn't mean it fixed the problem. If a mod decided that a question was so clearly off-topic that it warranted being closed single-handedly, then the presence of discussion comments (which we do read while reviewing) can't be enough by itself to say that mods shouldn't be allowed to just immediately keep the question closed. And if it's in the queue because of an ineffectual edit, I can't see any reason why a mod shouldn't complete the review.
What about those borderline cases where a mod may have just considered it off-topic, but other community members disagree? Well beyond the comments, which the mods do read, there is always Meta, where the closure of specific questions can be discussed in detail. This is the intended way for moderation disputes to be resolved.

The question linked above has a little bit unusual context surrounding it. I consider it to be a very straightforward Latin grammar explanation question, which is off-topic on this site. It is phrased as a "why" question, which is the worst Wh-question to use in linguistics as it's ambiguous as to whether it's actually asking for how the grammar works (off-topic) or why the language evolved this way (basically unanswerable, although details of how Latin changed could be explained.) Keelan said in the comments that it should be reopened because it "invites an answer based on historical / cognitive linguistic considerations", which I consider to be a very over-charitable reading of the question. There could be an interesting and substantial question on the topic, but the question as written is not one of them. We don't judge questions on how interesting and insightful a potential answer could be, but on what the text of the question actually says. And the actual text of the question looks like it is asking for an explanation of Latin grammar, based on two sections of a textbook that aren't clear to the asker. It even asks if the book has mixed up its conjunctions! This is not a question that is looking for a deep explanation of the nuances of how Latin evolved, but for an explanation of how these conjunctions work. (That's what I would have said had anyone taken the question to Meta for discussion.)
The broader context is that the question was from a user who has a long history of sub-standard questions and suspensions. It wasn't a question from a new user who should be treated with lots of gentleness and patience to help them learn how the site works.  This was a question from a 12-year site member who has asked many questions that are either clearly or borderline off-topic. In addition, they have started asking multiple questions about Latin here because they are suspended on the Latin site. Where there is an overlap between the sites, questions here need to be clearly focused on asking about linguistic matters, and not just how Latin works, which is why I reject that overly-charitable reading of the question. I don't want questions to just be cross-posted here if they're marginally on-topic; experienced users need to learn to tailor their questions for the site, to explicitly ask questions about the linguistics of a language and not just its usage. And it's not even like I'm saying all their Latin questions should be closed: no one even suggested that their question on clitics vs suffixes should be closed despite being very poor (while we can overlook new users not knowing basic concepts, I expect experienced users to use more than just a dictionary and be able to at least look up Wikipedia or other linguistic resources to know what is meant by a term like 'clitic') as I judged that it was asking for a linguistic explanation more than just a grammatical explanation.

Lastly I think this is a lot of hubbub over almost nothing. The fact is that I at least have already shifted my behaviour and rarely take unilateral action through the review queues. I've only made 2 reopen reviews this year (and skipped 2 others). But the problem is only 3 reopen reviews have been made by others this year! While a mod choosing "keep closed" does end the review so others can't review it, these numbers are not high enough that my "keep closed" review would have had any effect at all. Last year wasn't much different, I only did 6 out of 31 reopen reviews. The last time I could see a question being reopen by the community through reviews was once in Jun 2023, and then in Jan 2022. Before that, in Nov 2021 I said leave closed in a review, but the community still reopened it a few days later. While we do need more people reviewing, as far as I can see the way I've been reopen reviewing has not had any real practical effect on the site.
Despite that, I'll propose a compromise on policy: mods shouldn't unilaterally end a reopen review when they participated in the original closure for at least 7 days (which if the reopen review started immediately after the closure is when it would have auto-resolved anyway.)
Edit: or another potential compromise: a mod who closed a question can only vote "keep closed" if they would be the third person doing so. Which with how this site has been reviewing won't be a very common occurrence...
Even in non-exceptional circumstances I don't want us to have site policies that mean that, even with due care, mods are more restricted in using the site than regular users. Regular users can vote to keep closed on something they voted to close in the first place! So let's focus on ensuring that mod binding votes aren't misused rather than a blanket rule that mods can't act on something twice. If the community doesn't trust us to do that then perhaps this second compromise could work. I suggested the third review as there are so few reopen reviews in the first place, so a third would be close enough to showing consensus.

I agree with almost all of this, except the 7 days clause. Of course, in cases of blatant abuse of rules, mods should still be able to override all of it. I recall around 4-5 people who had around 5 accounts each. In one extreme case, one person has as many as 40 accounts. Most common courtesies are irrelevant when we are dealing with such edge cases.

@prash I also agree with almost all of this, and agree that the 7 day clause is not ideal. Unfortunately the answer does not attempt to address my points, those raised in the question and those in comments on curiousdannii's other answer. I can explain this point by point, but whether it is worth the effort depends on whether they are committed to whichever policy the community agrees upon.

@Keelan I'm committed to following the community determined site standards and policies, but those cannot include blanket rules that prevent the mods from acting in exceptional circumstances.

Do you feel yourself superior in some way?  What you repeated said here and elsewhere contradicts Bible teaching about how to treat other people and to think of yourself

So what will you do if the community is in favor of what you see as “blanket rules”? Resign? How do you imagine going forward doing something you are explicitly asked, by majority and with support of a fellow moderator, not to do?

@Keelan Probably bring in staff to mediate, seeing as that would be a sign of substantial community breakdown, if the community as a whole is declaring they don't trust the mod team.

I've suggested another compromise possibility. Even in non-exceptional circumstances I don't want us to have site policies that mean that, with due care, mods can only use the site less than regular users. Regular users can vote to keep closed on something they voted to close in the first place. So let's focus on ensuring that mod binding votes aren't misused. If you don't trust us to do that then perhaps this second compromise could work. I suggested the third review as there are so few reopen reviews in the first place, but a third is close enough to showing consensus.

I appreciate you trying to find alternatives. However, this answer is based on a misconception crucial for the issue at hand. You write, "mods aren't a separate class ... who can only utilise their mod powers", and: "I don't want ... that, even with due care, mods are more restricted in using the site than regular users". This is already the case, since mods do not have non-binding close/reopen votes. If mods would have non-binding votes, I would not be opposed to those being used in cases such as these. Given that there are only binding votes, we need to figure out how (not) to use them.

Furthermore, this answer incorrectly frames my proposal as if it suggests "blanket rules". I propose guidelines for some very specific circumstances. From the example question it is clear that I am not talking about closed questions where an inconsequential edit has been made, or where all discussion comes from the OP themselves who clearly misunderstands the site's scope. In the example question - and more examples can be given - a reasoned argument for reopening was given by a site member with plenty of experience! You are framing the proposal as something unreasonable, which it is not.

To be sure, if it is easier for you, a "blanket rule" could work, because you still have not responded to my question what you think we gain exactly by handling these queue items yourself a second time. Why not let the community or another moderator handle them? If they are not fast enough, nothing happens; the question would stay closed. What is to be gained with this zeal? All you are doing is creating the semblance of a conflict of interest. It is frustrating for site members new and old, and discussing it takes much more time than I would like to spend on it.

You have now written two answers that put an incorrect spin on my proposals and many comments that repeatedly evade my points. Vote counts show mixed agreement with your point of view, and considerably more agreement with that expressed in my question and Draconis' answer. I don't see a way forward here, so maybe it is best to bring in someone from StackExchange, Inc indeed.

@Keelan Indeed I want to know what is to gain from your zeal too. I apologise for finishing the review of that one question so quickly. I wish we could have just left it at that rather than making up new rules. I'm not spinning anything about your proposals, I'm simply presenting my own view.

It's good to hear that you're not talking about inconsequential edits, but nothing in your main proposal above indicates that. Your actual concrete proposal has no such nuance. I don't think it was unfair to call it a blanket rule.

So, once again you do not address my arguments and questions. I'll assume that you follow the proposal going forward, considering the vote counts, or that you contact Stack Exchange, Inc, if you don't want to.

I support the mods not handling flags on their own posts or comments, but I don't support a blanket rule that mods can't keep closed via the review queue. We already have a simple way to dispute moderator closure: discuss it in Meta.
If a mod sees a question in the reopen queue that appears blatantly off-topic, and no reasonable arguments in the comments for why it should be reopened, then I don't think there's anything wrong with them keeping it closed, even if they were one of the original close voters.
Do remember that that doesn't actually stop others from continuing to vote to reopen it. If a question does get reopened, then a mod shouldn't close it again, but instead they would need to argue in Meta for why the question should be closed.

I did not suggest a "blanket rule that mods can't keep closed via the review queue". I suggested two specific circumstances under which they should not do this: when there is discussion in the comments, or when they voted to close themselves before. The case you mention ("appears blatantly off-topic, and no reasonable arguments in the comments") is separate from this.

The point is not that a mod's leave closed vote would "stop others from continuing to vote to reopen it". The point is that it removes a question from the queue and makes it less visible. Since you specifically are very active in the review queues, many questions are dealt with before other users ever get to see them. That is often a good thing, but not in these cases, I believe. So I stand by all three my suggestions, and would still like to know whether you also support the last two.

Could you address these comments please?

@Keelan I don't have much more to say. The issue is that whether a specific case counts is blatantly off-topic or a much more nuanced is a matter of judgement. The real problem is not that we disagree on how to handle flags and the review queues, but that at times we'll disagree on what is blatantly off-topic. I don't think it's worth spending much more time discussing it ahead of time, when we can't predict what sort of weird questions will be posted in the future.

If it isn't clear, I emphatically reject your last two proposals and will not be following them. If you reworded them to exclude the blatantly off topic questions, then sure I'd agree to them, but it wouldn't change the way I moderate. Beyond the ways in which you've pressured me to change years ago.  I hope you can recognise how much I'm accommodating your demands already.

On the other hand, there is a flag on one of might comments right now. It's the third time a flag has been raised on that comment by the same user with the same complaint. The previous two were declined by the two other mods. Am I allowed to decline it myself now?

You wrote in your answer: "If a mod sees a question in the reopen queue that appears blatantly off-topic, and no reasonable arguments in the comments for why it should be reopened". However, in this and similar cases there was a comment explaining a reopen vote, which received upvotes from others, and at least one other reopen vote. We can debate whether it is off topic, but the possibility of debate shows that it is not blatantly off topic. And you have not responded to my request to recognize such discussion as an indication that a question is not blatantly off topic -- please do.

I am afraid I cannot recognize at all how much you are accommodating any demands. I have honestly no idea what you are referring to. To my memory, you have always rejected any suggestion I have made, or simply ceased to respond. I find this very problematic, as the vote counts on this question, its answers and comments thereon indicate that I am not the only one who feels this way. You even have a fellow moderator who agrees with these suggestions.

It is not clear to me why it is such a big deal for you to deal with these flags and review items yourself, instead of letting the community or other moderators handle them. If I were to moderate I would want to avoid even the appearance of a conflict of interest. If a decision of mine were to be contested I would back off and let others handle them - that's why you are a team; that's why the community can review as well. What is gained by swooping in before anyone else can have a look?

@Keelan No, I don't reject your suggestions, and have changed my behaviour to skip lots of questions in the review queues I previously would have just immediately acted on. I also rarely even visit the queues now, although I do admit the question you linked above was handled the same day. How would you feel about a 7 day period after which a mod could handle the review of something they've already handled? That's a compromise I'd be willing to take.

I've only done 2 reopen reviews this year (and skipped two others). But only 3 reopen reviews have been made by others this year! Last year I did 6 out of 31 reopen reviews. While a mod choosing keep closed would prevent others from reviewing it, these are very low numbers. The last time I could see a question being reopen by the community through reviews was Jan 2022. Before that, in Nov 2021 I said leave closed in a review, but the community still reopened it a few days later. I don't think the way I've been reviewing has any practical effect.

Well, you have not responded to my points that (a) discussion about closure indicates that a question is not blatantly off topic, and (b) what is gained by handling these items yourself instead of leaving them for others. But if you feel strongly about it, a 7 day wait period is an acceptable compromise.

@curiousdannii Policy is determined by writing and voting on meta posts, not by negotiating compromises with individual users. If you want to propose a policy, I suggest (1) stating your commitment to follow whichever answer gets the most agreement even if you disagree with it (re: "I emphatically reject your last two proposals and will not be following them"), and (2) writing a new answer with your proposed policy

@ba If the mods had been reviewing against the community agreed upon site standards that would be a big problem. But this discussion is saying that mods shouldn't do their jobs and enforce the site standards. And there hasn't been a single example presented where the actions of mods actually kept a question closed that the community determined should be open.

@ba But I will sum up these comments in a new post.

Now that there are two competing answers, if vote counts show agreement with Draconis’ answer, are you committed to following it, as @ba suggests?
